# List of string into List of object by splitting the string by delimiter

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a list of string:

```
var list = new List<string>();
```

Data in the list is in this format `A1_A2_A3`, `A1_A2_A3`, `A1_A2_A3`

I want to split each element `A1_A2_A3` of list by `_` and store the result into `List<Item>`

Where `Item` is a class containing three properties `a1`, `a2`, `a3`

I want to do it using LINQ, I can do this by using loop but I'm looking for solution using LINQ Only

Here is my working:

```
list.Select(x => x.Split('_').Select(s => new Item()
                {
                    a1 = x[0],
                    a2 = x[1],
                    a3 = x[2]
                }))
```

Comment: you'll probably need to tell split which character to use, `x.Split("_")` for the underscore.

Comment: Yes, I forget to add `x.Split("_")`. I've updated my question

Comment: What do you mean with "linq only"? I can see *only* linq-code in your question.

Comment: @HimBromBeere They should have said "Here is my non-working attempt:"

Comment: @HimBromBeere, for the linq only, I meant that I'm looking for solution in linq although it solution can also be achieved using loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to do is take each part of the split and put in a different property:

```
var result = list.Select(x => {
    var parts = x.Split('_');
    return new Item { a1 = parts[0], a2 = parts[1], a3 = parts[2] };
}).ToList();
```

Note that this does not check for value index passed to indexer. If you want to verify then you could:

```
var result = list.Select(x => {
        var parts = x.Split('_');
        return parts.Length == 3 ? new Item { a1 = parts[0], a2 = parts[1], a3 = parts[2] : null };
    }).Where(i => i != null).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to split on `'_'` and your selects are off, you first need to select the `Split` result and then you index into the result array, your code indexes into the original string (`x`)

```
var list = new List<string>();
list
    .Select(x => x.Split('_'))
    .Select(s => new Item()
    {
        a1 = s[0],
        a2 = s[1],
        a3 = s[2]
    });
```